# iOS: how to get and set cookies for a nsurlconnection in objective C

Tags: ios, cookies, nsurlconnection

I have a login screen, when the user enters username password, and logs in, a `JSESSIONID` cookie is given back. Now I need to set this cookie for the subsequent POST requests the user will be performing on other screens. In Android it was as simple as using `getCookieStore()` and `setCookieStore()`. Are there any similar methods in objective C? I can't find any.
Right now the login works but further requests give me back JSONs saying that the session is not valid instead of giving me the data I need. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546495/how-to-get-cookies-and-use-them-for-other-requests-like-post-ios

Comment: This is also a viable solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660927/iphone-make-post-request-handle-cookie?rq=1